# Rails: How to use the find method on an arbitrary index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find, unique-index

I have created a model that has a string as a unique identifier.
I created a migration to add an index on that string and set it to be unique.
How can i access a database entry by just passing its unique identifier string to the find method, for example

```
@object = Object.find(params[:unique_id])
```

At the moment, all i get is an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception...

> Couldn't find Object with id=abc

...when i try to access `Object.find('abc')`

The `where` method is no alternative as this gives me back a relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.find(:unique_id)` searches on the column 'object_id'; If you want to search on an other column, use `Object.find_by_[column_name]!(:unique_id)`. This will raise an exception if the record can't be found, as would do the `find` method.

Comment: That gives me the following
`irb(main):006:0> Object.find_by_unique_id(:unique_id => 'abc')
ArgumentError: Unknown key: unique_id`
My migration is `add_index :objects, :unique_id, unique: true`
When i use where, it works